# No Width on asp:TextBox on IE11

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, width

the Widths (and Heights) are not correct on my IE 11. All other Browsers works fine.

But:
on the project Development (W7, IIS 8, VS2013) at my Development PC its all OK on IE 11

and then: if I get the same site from my V-Server in the Web, the IE shows all Textboxes with the same width.(on Web: Windows Server Web 2007, SP2, IIS6)
With the F12-Key I checked the Code and I have seen, that there are no With-Tag for the Textboxes.

I dont know what to do - can somebody help me? (all under MS FW4)
Thank you
Grüße von Torsten

My Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 

"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
  <meta content="IE=8" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" />
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
      <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Width="100px"></asp:TextBox>
      <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Width="50px"></asp:TextBox>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Modify your `meta` tag to `IE=edge` instead of `IE=8`

```
<meta content="IE=edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" />
```

Comment: Thanks for this - but unfortunately the problem persists.